# Web Service only accepts HelloWorld as method name

Tags: web-services

I created a web service and once I tested that the default HelloWorld method is being called properly in my ajax method, I removed it, added another method and rerun the steps as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx).

Now, I receive this error.

error: 500 - System.InvalidOperationException: LoadAllFeeds Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
 - Internal Server Error

But when I bring back the method name to HelloWorld (and again run the steps in the msdn doc) it goes ok.

I am clueless, I hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: what is the other name that you are trying?

Comment: LoadAllFeeds (as stated above), LoadFeeds, GetAllFeeds, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I overlooked my project and saw that I have an existing version of my web service which only contains the HelloWorld default method. Haaay, stupid me. Sorry for bothering you about this.

Comment: write about the solution in the answer and mark it as right

Answer (score 1):

write `[WebMethod]` on the top of the function like

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

     [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return list;
    }
```